# cannot export react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having this file:

*Product.jsx*:

```
class Product extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='item'>
                <div className='image'>
                    <img src="images/products/image-aqua.png" />
                </div>
                <div className="middle aligned content">
                    <div className="description">
                        <a>Fort Knight</a>
                        <p>Authentic renaissance actors, delivered in just two weeks.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="extra">
                        <span>Submitted by:</span>
                        <img src="images/avatars/daniel.jpg" className="ui avatar image" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Product;
```

and *ProductList.jsx*:

```
import Product from "./Product";

class ProductList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='ui unstackable items'>
                <Product />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProductList />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The React Class `<Product />` is not rendered (If I try to simply paste the Product class into ProductList.jsx, no problem then, but I want separate files for each class, how to achieve that?)

Comment: No errors? Just doesn't render?

Comment: In `ProductList.jsx` do `console.log(Product)` right after the import statement. What do you get?

Comment: If you are using `react` class components, you need to import react

Answer (score 0):

Use in Product.jsx the  `import React from "react";`

demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qsbnm3?file=Product.js)

Answer (score 0):

1. First import React at the top.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   ```
2. Second you might be giving the wrong address at the top. Make sure it is right. You know the path well. Apart from these I don't see any problem with the code.

   ```
   import Product from "./Product";
   ```